# cURL issue on php5

Tags: php, curl, installation

I recently change my server to php5, the below code was working good on old server(php 4)
but now it stop working on my new server(php5). Its not showing any error message.

```
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

    $ch = curl_init();                                                    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url to post to 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);// allow redirects 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // times out after 10s 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // set POST method 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "category=".$heading."&county=".$county."&sorttype=1"); // add POST fields 

    $myHeader = array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept-Charset: utf-8");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $myHeader); 

    $result = curl_exec($ch); // run the whole process 

    curl_close($ch);
```

Please help me if there anything I need to care between php4 and php5

Comment: Does `curl_error()` report anything?

Comment: Thanks! I tried `curl_error()` but not return anything :(

Comment: By "not working", do you mean that `$result` contains nothing? What's the difference result between your old server and new server?

Comment: Yes, the $result is empty.

Comment: @Passerby `cURL support  enabled
cURL Information  7.19.7
Age -3
Features
AsynchDNS  No
Debug  No
GSS-Negotiate  Yes
IDN  Yes
IPv6  Yes
Largefile  Yes
NTLM  Yes
SPNEGO  No
SSL  Yes
SSPI  No
krb4  No
libz  Yes
CharConv  No
Protocols  tftp, ftp, telnet, dict, ldap, ldaps, http, file, https, ftps, scp, sftp
Host  x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version  NSS/3.13.1.0
ZLib Version  1.2.3
libSSH Version  libssh2/1.2.2 `    This is my new curl config and  the old one is `CURL support  enabled
CURL Information  libcurl/7.12.1 OpenSSL/0.9.7a zlib/1.2.1.2 libidn/0.5.6 `

Comment: Use `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,true);curl_setopt(CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,true)` and `curl_getinfo()` to track the in/out headers and see if everything is expected. And you can update the info into the question.

Comment: Add your postfields like an array